# Celery raise MemoryError

Tags: django, celery

I'm using celery 4.3.0,And use it to generate a image which maybe 10M+,Then I got an error like below:

```
Pool callback raised exception: MemoryError('Process got: ')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*/lib/python3.7/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1750, in safe_apply_callback
    fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "*/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/worker/request.py", line 564, in on_success
    return self.on_failure(retval, return_ok=True)
  File "*/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/worker/request.py", line 351, in on_failure
    raise MemoryError('Process got: %s' % (exc_info.exception,))
```

My server has 20G+ memory left when running this task.And I had test some small images which work well.Do I need set some config to prevent this?

Comment: Do you have the [max-memory-per-child](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#max-memory-per-child-setting) setting set?

Comment: No,And I found if not set this config which means no limit.

Comment: The fact that the final output is a ~10M image does not mean the process of creating it (your task) will not allocate 20G in order to make that image... You should profile that code and find out what is allocating memory. Also, you may have multiple processes running, all allocating memory... - At some point one task will fail because there is no available memory left.

Comment: I think this is because one task or one process can't allocate this memory.I use top command when running this task,And found there is 20G memory left.

Comment: Keep in mind that you have N worker processes all possibly running the same task concurrently (you did not tell us what is your preferred concurrency type so we can only guess). They will allocate memory and then the unlucky task will try to allocate and fail because there is no available RAM left because most of it was consumed by other tasks. Run `top` or `htop` and you will be able to see it...

Comment: What you say were right.Just like what I had I said on last comment,I had use `top` command and find there was 20G ram left.And I had test many times, When doing the same task the exception were all be raised.